# jquery background image url failed

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is not working ....

```
$("#news_all ul li").css("background", "transparent url('../images/01.png') no-repeat");
```

but this is working

```
.news_all_item li {
    background: url("../images/01.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}
```

My html

```
<div class="news_all_item" id="news_all">
  <ul>
   <li><div class="news_item">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesettiLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</div></li>
   <li><div class="news_item">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesettiLorem Ipsum </div></li>
   <li><div class="news_item">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetti</div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: They are two different selectors? is that a typo?  Also you are setting more options in your css than when you set it with jquery.

Comment: I can see your code is working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/h6nqU/. Do you see any errors on the console? Say 404 Not Found for image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because of the relative link.

I suspect your style sheet probably is in the css folder; and the javascript is probably written in your html, which is in the root folder.

In the style sheet "../images/" is valid because from folder css, '../' goes back one level (to the root folder) then '/images' access the images folder. But from the root folder you'll have to omit the ../ (doesn't need to go back a level anymore).

Anyway if you're using relative link, keep in mind the starting point of the path is where the code is written.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps path may a problem.(**Give absolute** path if you can. i.e. `assets/style/images/01.png`)

in css file `../images/01.png` may exist but from js file `../images/01.png` may not exist

You may have a folder structure like.

```
asset
     |-->style
          |-->css
               |-->mycss.css
          |-->images
               |-->01.png
     |-->js
          |-->myjs.js
```

so here from css `../images/01.png` is valid but from js file the same thing is not valid

Comment: i think so, bcoz i can see the code works with the valid path http://jsfiddle.net/h6nqU/

Answer (score 0):

Use background-image instead of background..

```
$("#news_all ul li").css("background-image", "transparent url('../images/01.png') no-repeat");
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `background-image`, not `background`, as the attribute key.

Comment: I also used this 

$("#news_all ul li:nth-child(2)").css('background-image', "url('../images/01.png')");

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to set the background you can apply via class selector ".news_all_item" instead of "#news_all_item"

```
 $(".news_all_item li").css("background", "transparent url('../Encounters/LandingPage.PNG') no-repeat");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$( "ul#news_all> li" ).css("background", "transparent url('../images/01.png') no-repeat");
```